# Feedparser (and urllib2) issue: Connection timed out

Tags: python, rss, urllib2, urllib, feedparser

Starting with `urllib2` and `feedparser` libraries in Python I'm getting the following error most of the time whenever try to connect and fetch content from particular URL:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

The minimal reproducible examples (basic, using `feedparser.parser` directly and advanced, where I use `urllib2` library first to fetch XML content) are pasted below.

```
# test-1
import feedparser
f = feedparser.parse('http://www.zurnal24.si/index.php?ctl=show_rss')
title = f['channel']['title']
print title

# test-2
import urllib2
import feedparser
url = 'http://www.zurnal24.si/index.php?ctl=show_rss'
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
request = opener.open(url)
response = request.read()
feed = feedparser.parse(response)
title = feed['channel']['title']
print title
```

When I try with different URL addresses (e.g., `http://www.delo.si/rss/`), everything works fine. Please note that all URL's lead to non-english (i.e., Slovenian) RSS feeds.

I run my experiments both from local and remote machine (via `ssh`). The error reported occurs more frequently on remote machine, although it's unpredictable even on local host.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How often does the timeout occur? If it's not frequent, you could wait after each timeout and then retry the request:

```
import urllib2
import feedparser
import time
import sys

url = 'http://www.zurnal24.si/index.php?ctl=show_rss'
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

# Try to connect a few times, waiting longer after each consecutive failure
MAX_ATTEMPTS = 8
for attempt in range(MAX_ATTEMPTS):
    try:
        request = opener.open(url)
        break
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        sleep_secs = attempt ** 2
        print >> sys.stderr, 'ERROR: %s.\nRetrying in %s seconds...' % (e, sleep_secs)            
        time.sleep(sleep_secs)

response = request.read()
feed = feedparser.parse(response)
title = feed['channel']['title']
print title
```

Comment: Sometimes I can retrieve 10 consecutive requests until error, sometimes not even single one.

Answer (score 3):

As the error denotes, it is a connection problem. This may be a problem with your internet connection or with their servers/connection/bandwidth..

A simple workaround is to do your feedparsing in a while loop, of course keeping a counter of MAX retries..